# Kotlin OkHTTP3 Await() function not returning response body

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I'm new to mobile development, I am trying to implement a mobile app for my website. Doing so I have used okhttp3 to make post and get requests to my web app. Which seems to work okay within a callback.

My issue is this, I want to get data from the response and move to the next fragment if it is the correct data. I.E. a login page.

I tried to use okhttp3's .execute over .enqueue, to no avail. Which led me to coroutines and await(), seen here: https://github.com/gildor/kotlin-coroutines-okhttp

Using await allows me to ditch the callback, and switch fragments after getting the response. But I am not able to retrieve the "Body" of the response, just the response code, message, request, headers, etc. Here is a snippet of my code with enqueue and the await, the enqueue response includes the body, the await line "println(result.body?.string())" gives me a fatal exception on main.

```
private suspend fun request(): Int {
    //on button click
    val url = "https://redacted/mobile/login"
    Log.i("Testing", "Attempting Client Connection")

    val formBody: RequestBody = FormBody.Builder()
        .add("username", binding.usernameInput.text.toString())
        .add("password", binding.passwordInput.text.toString())
        .build()

    val client1 = OkHttpClient()
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

    val request = Request.Builder()
        .post(formBody)
        .url(url)
        .build()

    val result = client.newCall(request).await()
    println(result.request)
    println(result.networkResponse)
    println(result.priorResponse)
    println(result.cacheResponse)
    println(result.headers)
    println(result.body.toString())
    println(result.body?.string())
    println(result)
    println("${result.code}: ${result.message}, ${result.body}")

    client1.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            // Handle this
            Log.i("Testing", e.toString())
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            // Handle this
            val body = response.body?.string()
            if (body != null) {
                Log.i("Testing", body.toString())
                if (body.contains("Login successful", ignoreCase = true)) { 
                    // makes it to here but fails to apply the following line
                    binding.apply {
                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    return result.code
}
```